# In WPF, how can I allow only a single cell to be selected in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want it to only be possible to select one cell in a DataGrid. With multi select disabled, you can still select a range of cells, but I want it to only allow a single-cell selection. Is there any way to do this through the properties? Or will I have to intercept the selection and filter out everything but one cell?

Comment: What control are you using? Might be sort of critical to the answer.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth yeah thanks. Didn't realize I left that out. It's a DataGrid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `DataGrid` has a `SelectionUnit` property of type [`DataGridSelectionUnit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridselectionunit.aspx), in conjunction with [`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectionmode.aspx):

> The SelectionMode and SelectionUnit properties together define the
>   selection behavior for the DataGrid.

Try setting `SelectionUnit` to `Cell`. This will work with both `SelectionMode` values:

> If the selection mode is Extended, the user can select multiple items
>   where the item type is defined by the SelectionUnit property. If the
>   selection mode is Single, the user can only select single items.

To select a single cell, use `SelectionMode` of `Single` and `SelectionUnit` of `Cell`:

> The SelectionMode and SelectionUnit properties together determine how
>   users can select items in a DataGrid. For example, if the
>   SelectionMode is Single and the SelectionUnit is Cell, the user can
>   select only one cell at a time in the DataGrid.

Comment: I guess I just forgot to set the SelectionMode property but thought I did.

Comment: Sorry for getting mad at you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the SelectionUnit of the DataGrid. It defines the scope of one selection unit. It can be set to Cell, CellAndRowHeader and FullRow.

Example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" />
```